# Whats that number?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You find a mysterious paper with the following chars on it : "`§!=)`"

Plus the note :

"It has something to do with `C _ M _ _ T _ R S`

And a `G _ _ M _ N   _ _ _ O U T`"

What number do the chars `§!=)` stand for ?

Comment: Are you sure about the first blank? I have a word that fits perfectly except for one extra blank...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think

> The incomplete words on the note make it read "It has something to do with COMPUTERS and a GERMAN LAYOUT"

So

> Looking up the German keyboard layout, the four characters on the paper result from Shift+3, Shift+1, Shift+0, and Shift+9 in that order, and the number being 3109.